# Get the value associated with maximum per group

Tags: sql, mysql, string, greatest-n-per-group

I'm struggling on something very simple and it's making me crazy. I'm using MySQL and PHPMyadmin.
Basically, I have a table containing urls, ids (unique) and source.
Each source has sometime several urls.

I simply want to **longest url per source. **

I have something like this:

| pid | source | url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 127 | a-url |
| 2 | 127 | a-longer-url |
| 3 | 128 | some-kind-of-url |
| 4 | 128 | some-url |

And I'm trying to display:

| pid | source | url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 127 | a-longer-url |
| 3 | 128 | some-kind-of-url |

So, simply getting the longer url per source.

I've been trying stuff like:

```
SELECT pid, source, MAX(LENGTH(url)), url FROM table GROUP BY source
```

but though it displays the right maximum length in number I cannot fetch the right url string, as it displays another one than the longest.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions to rank rows having the same `source` by the length of their `url`, then select the top row(s) per group:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, rank() over(partition by source order by char_length(url) desc) rn 
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

This returns top ties, if any; else, you would need an additional sorting criteria in the `order by` clause of the window function.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer ! (And for the editing btw, somehow the presentation got screwed when I posted, the preview was fine)
Sadly, I don't have access to Window functions !
I managed to find a workaround during night though. I did this:
INSERT IGNORE INTO new_order (source,url)  SELECT DISTINCT source,url AS aliases
FROM url_alias
ORDER BY LENGTH(alias) DESC
By doing so I got a table with all rows in order of length.
Then I inserted it in a new table "New order" and took the first value per source.
Thanks for your help !